# Select only the parents where any of the children's names do not contain a specific string

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm using Linq to retrieve data from context. I'm trying to get only the parent `CategoryAttributeItemDescriptions` items that do not have a grandchild `AttributeItems` with an internal name containing the word "Range -" 
The code below is where I am currently.

```
var query = from caid in context.CategoryAttributeItemDescriptions
                    join cai in context.CategoryAttributeItems on caid.Id  equals cai.CategoryAttributeItemDescriptionsId
                    join ai in context.AttributeItems on cai.AttributeId equals ai.Id
                    where caid.CategoryAttributeItems.Any(c => !c.AttributeItem.InternalName.Contains("Range -")) && caid.CategoryId ==element.Id
                    select caid;
```

The problem is that it is still returning parents that have a relation to grandchildren with that internal name. Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: try changing the where clause to    'where caid.CategoryAttributeItems.Any(c => !c.AttributeItem.InternalName.Contains("Range -")) && caid.CategoryId ==element.Id'

Comment: basically add the exclamation mark before the c.AttributeIte.... this translates to 'Not'

Comment: i may be reading this incorrectly above, but aren't you loking FOR matches in the Any() predicate, rather than exclusing??

Comment: I have added the exclamation point (silly mistake), however, it is still only ignoring parents that have all grandchildren with this internalname, instead of parents with only one for example.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like wrong logic.

This

```
caid.CategoryAttributeItems.Any(c => !c.AttributeItem.InternalName.Contains("Range -"))
```

according to your requirement should be

```
!caid.CategoryAttributeItems.Any(c => c.AttributeItem.InternalName.Contains("Range -"))
^                            ^         ^
do not                       have      with an internal name containing the word "Range -"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, the problem is, if one of the grandchildren contains the name 'Range -', then the parent is not discounted and is still added to query. I want to completely ignore the parent if any of the grandchildren have this name.

Comment: I didn't analyze the whole query, but now I see that the `joins` are redundant and multiply the results set, so you'd better remove them. Although that's another issue. By `parent` you mean `caid` and grandchildren 'caid.CategoryAttributeItems`, right? Are you sure you applied exactly the suggestion in the answer? `!Any(Contains())` should do exactly what you want.

Comment: caid is indeed the parent, the attributeItems are the grandchildren. I noticed that the results were duplicating so was using Distinct. However, it is too late at this point as the attributeitems with 'Range' have been added.